# Is there an alternative to textSplice that does not escape the content?

Tags: haskell, heist

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/heist-1.0.1.0/docs/Heist-Interpreted.html#v:textSplice
`textSplice` appears to escape the contents. It replaces `<` to `&lt;` for example.

How can I avoid this escaping behaviour?

Comment: From its source code, it seems that it creates an unescaped [`Text.XmlHtml.Node`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmlhtml-0.2.3.5/docs/Text-XmlHtml.html#t:Node) value. The escaping is probably done elsewhere later on.

Comment: Hmm, I should have tried an example of this function in isolation. Will modify the question once confirmed.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the escaping behavior by parsing the whatever you want to include into a list of `Node`s and then returning those directly.  Here's the function you want:

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmlhtml-0.2.3.5/docs/Text-XmlHtml.html#v:parseHTML

Comment: But... the source says `textSplice t = return [X.TextNode t]` so `textSplice` already does not escape. The actual issue is probably somewhere else. Probably there's some serializer somewhere that assumes the text in the nodes is to be escaped (?)

Comment: Everything in a `TextNode` gets escaped automatically.  If you don't want it to get escaped you need to parse it first.  Then don't call `textSplice`.  Return the nodes given to you by `parseHTML` directly.